# heroku push postgres WINDOWS 10

Tags: bash, postgresql, heroku

First of all don't mark its repeated question because its not, I tried both installing bash not work, tried put on path postgres variable didn't work at all

```
C:\Users\xxx>heroku pg:push postgres postgresql-dbname --app appname
heroku-cli: Pushing postgres ---> postgresql-parallel-57681
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Attempt on windows bash

```
C:\Users\USER>bash
root@Miguel-Laptop:/mnt/c/Users/USER# heroku pg:push postgres postgresql-DBNAME --app APPNAME
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: @echo: Permission denied
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: %~dp0\node.exe: Permission denied

heroku-cli/6.14.42-3ba878b (windows-x86) node-v9.2.0
```

Comment: have you tried with `sudo heroku ...` ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that on windows 10 environment.

Comment: my attempts on bash windows failed. heroku: command not found

Comment: either install heroku on bash on windows (with `sudo apt-get install heroku`) or try `sudo heroku.exe ...` in bash on windows

Comment: root@XXX-Laptop:/mnt/c/Users/XXXX# sudo apt-get install heroku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku
root@XXX-Laptop:/mnt/c/Users/~XXX# sudo heroku.exe
sudo: heroku.exe: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using WSL on Windows 10 Try installing Heroku via curl

```
$ curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Then run Heroku -v and you should get something like:

```
heroku/7.19.4 linux-x64 node-v11.3.0
```

If that doesn't work there's a great [GitHub thread here](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/600) with various solutions.